# How to embed/mount existing Rails app into another Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two Rails apps (using rails 3.0.7), call them "blog" and "auth". I'd like to mount "auth" from "blog" such that I can run the "blog" app and have certain requests routed to the "auth" app.

It seems like I need to embed or perhaps create an "engine", but I'm not 100% sure which is correct.

How can I embed the "auth" app inside of the "blog" app?

Comment: creating an engine is the way to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Rails was raising `RuntimeError: You cannot have more than one Rails::Application` if you attempted to have two Rails apps defined in one Ruby instance, but it has changed after [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/08dc92421a3c08383dd9cd4c2c62966e8d4c9560) commit.

This is still unreleased in 4.0.0, but will get included in the newer versions. (> 4.1.0.beta)

Check out [the discussion on PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9655) for more info.

---

From what I understand, you probably don't need to have two Rails apps, though. You should probably attempt to extract functionality you need in the `Rails::Engine`.

[Remember, `Rails::Application` is also a `Rails::Engine`.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L54)

You can find a lot of material about how to do it on the web, and I would recommend [these](http://blog.socialcast.com/taming-rails-apps-with-engines/) [two](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/migrating-from-a-single-rails-app-to-a-suite-of-rails-engines) to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

You can create "rails-engine" for 'auth' app, and then mount this engine into the rails application i.e 'blog' application.

Read more about Rails::Engine at below links -

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html

To embed a Rails mountable engine into a Rails application, follow these general steps -

1) Open the target Rails project, where an engine should be embedded.

2) Open for editing the Gemfile, and add the following line:

```
gem '<engine name>', :path => "<absolute path to the Rails mountable engine project>"
```

3) Open for editing Config/routes.rb, and add the following line:

```
 mount <engine name>::Engine, :at => "/<engine name>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails3 is a rack-based application. Rackmiddleware already has a number default built-in applications. Try to run **bundle exec rake middleware**. You can add custom Rack applications into the stack. Use [this](http://inductor.induktiv.at/blog/2010/05/23/mount-rack-apps-in-rails-3/) blogpost to see how it works.

Comment: I've seen that post but I'm left wondering, how would I make my "blog" application require the "auth" application? It's not as though the "auth" rails app is a gem I can just add to the Gemfile in my "blog" app.

Comment: I don't understand, do you need to add authentication into your application?

Comment: I have a rails app, named 'auth', that provides authentication. I'd like the client code of my "blog" rails app to GET/POST, etc to the 'auth' app. I can't do this straight from the JavaScript code in the 'blog' client b/c of JSONP (only GET's work). I want to essentially mount the "auth" app in/from the "blog" app so I can then access the auth. stuff from the client side code. Does that make sense? 

Right now I think my main issue is, how do I get the "auth" app mounted by the "blog" app? I can't just mount like that blog post suggests b/c the auth app isn't on the load path of the blog app.

Answer (score 0):

If auth app is something like a web service (for example facebook authentication), so just keep 2 apps running and make requests from one app with urls to another app.

If these apps share some logic or the same database, you can just merge the code, so two apps become one, or your can make 'auth' app something like a gem or a plugin and use it in your 'blog' app.

Comment: "just keep 2 apps running and make requests from one app with urls to another app." So from the client make requests to the other app? The initial plan was to have the client side of the "blog" app make requests to the "auth" app (using ajax) but that would require the use of JSONP which only allows for GET's. Some of the services I need to access require POST, DELETE, PUT, etc.

Comment: if you want to call one rails app to another use active resource.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics